# Postgresql Can't find any entries with `uniqueId NOT IN (null)`

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering why in Postgresql (and maybe other sql-dialets) the following Query leads to no entries (my_table has entires and uniqueid is a PK):

```
SELECT uniqueid FROM my_table where uniqueid not in (null)
```

Comment: `where uniqueid is not null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `IN (...)` clause has only one item in it, namely `NULL`, your query is identical to this:

```sql
SELECT uniqueid FROM my_table WHERE uniqueid != NULL;
```

Comparing any column/value against `NULL` is unknown and will never be true, and hence will never return any records.

Comment: alright, I came across it from a script where placeholders got replaced with null. Was able to fix it with an extra OR-Statement: ```(:ids IS NULL OR uniqueId NOT IN (:ids))```. Thanks!

Comment: @lordnik22 Are you using Java?

Comment: yes currently i'm working with java